# Spawning a maximum 3 instances of a commandline program using Python - how to wait till they're finished

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I'm trying to write a python script to run a transcoding program from the commandline, automating the process of converting a video stream from h264 to h265 with half the bitrate..

So far I'm reading a text file outputted by "mediainfo" with the filename and bitrate of each video file one line at a time.

I can parse the lines into variables and create a string to run the commandline NvEncC64.exe program..

This is where it gets slightly complicated. Using subprocess and os stuff detaches the process from the shell and runs it in the background.. This is fine - but the video encoder can only run three instances at a time as the graphics card runs out of resources.

I need a way to start three processes maximum and hold off launching any more instances of NvEncC64.exe till one of them finishes..

I have zero clue how to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: I can't tell you much without a code example.. But what I can suggest is that you use a queue with the subprocesses.. or multiprocessing and threading library, where you add processes to the queue, and pop them once they are joinable (as the process finishes)

Comment: I thought of keeping it much simpler than that. 

Basically, increment a “process” counter when a process is spawned, if this active process counter is 3 or above, halt reading the text file..but every way of spawning a process I’ve tried doesn’t return a result when the process finishes. Even if it did, how would I get the code to decrement the counter and start the loop up reading the next line in text file?  

Maybe I need to ditch hacking this and start from scratch - the handling of the processes and waiting for them to finish - before diving into the file handling stuff. :D